# how do make the background image on Xcode 6 swift

Tags: xcode, background, swift

Does anyone know what the code would be to make a background image that would cover the whole GameScene.swift

This is my code atm -

```
   import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playbutton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
    let score = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "score")
    var background = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "background")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        func loadBackGround()
        {
            background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
            background.name = "background"
            background.zPosition = 1.0
            background.size = self.scene.size
            scene.addChild(background)
        }


        self.playbutton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(self.playbutton)

        self.score.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100)
        self.addChild(self.score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to be more specific (iOS Game, Mac Game...), but I think something like this should work:

```
var bgImage:SKSpriteNode

func loadBackGround()
{
    bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BACKGROUND IMAGE NAME")
    bgImage.name = "bg"
    bg.size = self.scene.size
    scene.addChild(bg)
}
```

(you can use it outside of a function of course)

EDIT: Try this code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let playbutton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
let score = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "score")
var background = SKSpriteNode ()

func loadBackGround() // You define the function and what it does
{
    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.name = "background"
    background.size = self.scene.size
    scene.addChild(background)
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    loadBackGround() // You call the function you defined
    self.playbutton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(self.playbutton)

    self.score.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100)
    self.addChild(self.score)
}
```

Comment: Have you changed anything in your code like the anchorPoint or added any other sprites yet ? It might be the problem. Have you got any code to show us ?

Comment: You have to call the function loadBackground once for it to work :)

Comment: It's worked however the background image is not in the right place, its kind on placed it in the bottom left corner

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I use:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
super.init(size: size)

anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
addChild(background)
```

}

This loads the background image from the asset catalog and places it in the scene. Because the scene’s anchorPoint is (0.5, 0.5), the background image will always be centered on the screen on both 3.5-inch and 4-inch devices.

I get this from a good tutorial: [How to Make a Game Like Candy Crush with Swift Tutorial: Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1)